# Redirect user to a new page on anchor tag click through a ASPX page

Tags: asp.net, c#-3.0

My url is

http://mydomain/Mumbai-to-Paris-January-1023/Article.aspx

Now on click of this page I want the user to redirect to Article.aspx page where I will extract the Id on Page Load and pass it to my stored procedure.

My link is coming from my ASPX page here's the code:

```
    <% foreach (System.Data.DataRow item in dt.Rows)
         { 
            %>

                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 mix livefeeds News">
                        <div class="work-item">
                            <div class="image-holder">
                                <strong><a href="<%= "/"+ item["Url"]+"/"+ "Article.aspx"%>"></strong>
                                    <img src="<%=item["ImagePath"].ToString()%>"/>
                                    <h4>
                                        <span><%=item["Headline"].ToString()%></span>
                                        </h4>   
<strong>                                </a></strong>
                            </div>
                        </div>
             </div>


        <%
        }  
        %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Being specific to your question only, Change your anchor tag href like this :

> `<a href="<%= "/"+ item["Url"]+"/"+ "Article.aspx?id=1"%>">`

Comment: This will generated a url like http://mydomain/Article.aspx?Id=1 and I want http://mydomain/Mumbai-to-Paris-January-1023/Article.aspx,  basically its a query string before the aspx